# Active admin user model attribute not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, activeadmin

I added an attribute to admin_users model of active admin, the attribut was added using a migration, the code for the migration is :

```
class AddHostelToAdminUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :admin_users, :hostel, :string
  end
end
```

now when I am submitting the form to generate new admin I am getting nothing on place of that attribute ,the object is being created with out `:hostel` attribute
[image: Details of user]
see the hostel filled is empty. I entered all details carefully :
[image: Form for creating admin]

Comment: add attributes in permist

Comment: pfft.. I forgot..lol how can I..  btw thanks :)

Comment: Please update the question with the form code.

Comment: i Just forgot to  add attribute to permist !

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I just forgot to add attribute to permist !!

```
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:hostel
```

now its working well.